# Qt Show progress bar in dock (macOS)

Tags: macos, qt, progress, dock

I would like to show a progress bar in my app's icon in the macOS Dock like we can in Windows with QWinTaskbarProgress but I can't find how to do in internet.

Is it possible with Qt ?

I want something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUEWV.png

Answer (score 2):

There are two implementations I know of, although none have made it to Qt itself yet:

1. Qt Creator's progress manager:

   https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src/plugins/coreplugin/progressmanager
2. KDE's `MacDockProgressView`:

   https://cgit.kde.org/kdevplatform.git/tree/shell/macdockprogressview.h?id=c0626300e1c18448dd653a3484fd1ca6298e2d8c

   https://cgit.kde.org/kdevplatform.git/commit/?id=c0626300e1c18448dd653a3484fd1ca6298e2d8c